# Is there a possibility to use a .NET assembly in a non-CLR-Program?

Tags: .net, assemblies, clr

I'm developing a plugin for 3DsMax. So it is non-CLR C++. My question is, whether there is a possibility to use a .NET assembly within this plugin?

Thank you for your answers

Regards Nem.

Comment: Any use? http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/DotNet/DotNet-CPlusPlusClients.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however you will need to host the CLR within your application.

This is how IIS hosts ASP.NET websites, and how SQLServer allows for CLR functions etc.

Take a look at the CLR hosting API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx

Comment: TY, I think this answers my question perfectly. :)

Comment: The MSDN Magazine link is dead now. I couldn't find it's new URL, but here's a link to some of the documentation instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/index

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do it through COM-interop.

You can attribute a .NET assembly as exposing a COM interface, which can then be accessed by any native process that can use COM services.

Comment: This requires the .NET code to run in a separate process, I'd advocate for CLR hosting as it is self-contained.

Comment: You sure? It didn't use to be necessary and I'm struggling to find any reference that says it is, now.

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line is that if you want to use a .Net assembly, then you will need the CLR to run it.  There are a variety of ways to accomplish this in a native process including

- Hosting the CLR within the otherwise native process
- Running the assembly in a separate .Net process and communicating via COM interop

Comment: I don't think you need a separate process to use COM Interop. You certainly didn't it the good-ol' days of VB6-to-.NET.

Comment: @Steve you don't need a separate process for COM interop but if you do use a separate process COM can be a communication channel between the processes

Comment: OK, that I agree with ;-) I thought I was going mad for a moment, as I've never *needed* to run managed components out-of-process to use them from unmanaged code (as long as the CPU architecture was the same).